# Floating a png image on top of other images

Tags: html, css

So, I am trying to arrange 2 rows on top of one another, each containing 2 columns in bootsrtap 3. Each column has a different background color and occupies half of the screen.
I want to place a small png img right before the 2nd row begins and then to center it. The problem is that png image will totally separate the 2 rows and it creates a block for itself. A white background is made at both sides of the png image. I need to keep the 2 rows together, but how?

```css
    #row-polygon {
      display: block;
      width: 100%
      margin: none;
      padding: none;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    #divpolygon-top-left {
      display: inline-block;
      background: #992233;
      height: 250px;
    }
    #divpolygon-top-right {
      display: inline-block;
      background: #aa4433;
      height: 250px;
    }
    #dot {
      position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #divpolygon-bottom-left {
      display: inline-block;
      background: #229955;
      height: 250px;
    }
    #divpolygon-bottom-right {
      display: inline-block;
      background: #44bb77;
      height: 250px;
    }
```

```html
    <section id="section-polygon">
            <div class="row-polygon">
                <div id="divpolygon-top-left" class="col-xs-6">
                    <h3>Reason 1:</h3>
                </div>
                <div id="divpolygon-top-right" class="col-xs-6">
                    <h3>Reason 2:</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div><img id="dot" src="images/stop.jpg"></img></div>
            <div class="row-polygon">
                <div id="divpolygon-bottom-left" class="col-xs-6">
                    <h3>Reason 3:</h3>
                </div>
                <div id="divpolygon-bottom-right" class="col-xs-6">
                    <h3>Reason 4:</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: i will be more cleared if you add your code as a snippet

Comment: img - no closing tag

Comment: You should be able to just add display: block; position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto; to the image class and be good

Comment: Xariez, I followed what you said, but the img appears on top of the 1st row.

Comment: There is *no such tag* as `</img>`

Comment: Can you state more clearly where it is that you want the .png image to appear? Do you want it in the centre, overlapping with both columns in both rows. Or do you want it in the centre so that each of its 4 corners touches the respective corner of each column?

Comment: Rounin, I want the png img to be in the centre, between two rows, overlapping with both columns in both rows. In other words, the image will overlap/cover the bottom-right corner of top-left column, the bottom-left corner of the top-right column, the top-right corner of the bottom-left column and the top-left corner of the bottom-right column. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Still looking for a solution!